# Get the dtype of specific column with a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I want to display all my column with the dtypes.
For this I used to do `df.dtypes`. But in this dataframe I have 4000 column and I would also like to number them.

I tried something like this:

```
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
    with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
        print(i ,':',df.dtypes)
```

This obviously does not give me the expected result but you get the idea of what I need. How can I can use `df.dtypes` in a loop?

Comment: Isn't this `df.info()`?

Comment: Indeed, it's `df.info(verbose= True)`

Comment: Do you want a number (column number) *and* the column name, next to the dtype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
    with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
        print(i ,':',df.iloc[:,i].dtypes)
```

If you want column name also, then try this:

```
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
    with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
        print(i ,':',df.columns[i],df.iloc[:,i].dtypes)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you want, but this will print the column number (or some version of it), name and dtype, for the whole dataframe:

```
for i, (name, dtype) in enumerate(zip(df.columns, df.dtypes)):
    print(i, name, dtype)
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, this also works with `df.info(verbose= True)`

Comment: @QQ1821 So the correct answer is actually "Use `df.info(verbose=True)`"?

Comment: Yes, It gives the same result

Comment: You may then want to add your own answer for completion, just mentioning `df.info`, for completeness. Comments aren't always read, nor are they considered essential (though unfortunately, often they are).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print `dtypes` of all the columns, you can simply do `print(df.dtypes)` (but it also print `dtype: object` at the end).

If you want to print it as your own format, such as using `:`, you can do, as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'C': [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]
})

print(df)
#   A  B    C
#0  1  a  1.1
#1  2  b  2.2
#2  3  c  3.3

print(df.dtypes)
#A      int64
#B     object
#C    float64
#dtype: object

for col_name, dtype in df.dtypes.items():
    print(col_name, ":", dtype)

#A : int64
#B : object
#C : float64
```

Comment: So that only differs from printing `df.dtypes` directly by not having `dtype: object` at the end?

Comment: @9769953 Thank you for the comment. I updated my answer by considering your concern.